# OpenCart show weight units in product page 1.5.6

Tags: opencart

How can I show the the weight (with units) in product page in 1.5.6.
Example: Weight - 2.5 kg; Weight - 250 mg ...
I've been reading some articles, but nothing working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format weight with Opencart's weight class `format()` method like this:

```
$this->weight->format($weight,$weight_class_id);
```

The `getProduct()` method already supplies both values you need so you can easily call it from the product controller like so:

```
$this->data['product_weight'] = $this->weight->format($product_info['weight'],$product_info['weight_class_id']);
```

Then display `$product_weight` wherever you want in the tpl as you would any other variable. This will give you exactly what you want but with no space (i.e., '250mg').

If you want more control over the formatting, you can also get only the unit abbreviation (e.g., 'kg', 'oz', 'lb', etc) with the `getUnit()` method like this:

```
$this->weight->getUnit($product_info['weight_class_id']);
```

You could then put them together however you want.  If you want a space for instance:

```
$this->data['product_weight'] = $product_info['weight'] . ' ' .  $this->weight->getUnit($product_info['weight_class_id']);
```

Comment: Hey, can you send me you contacts on djroko@abv.bg

Comment: I doubt I am a genius, but I do work with Opencart a lot.  If you require commercial support, you can find me and many other knowledgeable developers on the official Opencart website: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=support/support

Answer (score 1):

```
go to catalog/language/english/product/product.php,Find:
```

$_['text_model']               = 'Product Code:';

Add below code after it

```
$_['text_weight']               = 'Weight:';
```

open catalog/controller/product/product.php, Find:

```
$data['text_stock'] = $this->language->get('text_stock');
```

Add below code after it:

```
$data['text_weight'] = $this->language->get('text_weight');
```

In same file search for the code:

```
$data['model'] = $product_info['model'];
```

Paste below code after it:

```
$data['weight'] = $product_info['weight'];
$tablewunit = $this->db->query("SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE (wcd.weight_class_id = " . $product_info['weight_class_id'] . ") AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
$data['weight_unit'] = $tablewunit->row['unit'];
```

Now open catalog/view/theme/---yourtheme---/template/product/product.tpl, and find:

```
<li><?php echo $text_stock; ?> <?php echo $stock; ?></li>
```

Add below code after it:

```
<td><b><?php echo $text_weight; ?></b></td>
 <td><?php echo round ($weight, 2) . ' ' . $weight_unit; ?></td> 
<tr> 
<?php if ($weight) { ?>
<tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Thats all

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow Bulgarian i assume by your name.

If you want to display weight on products it's very simple.

Open your FTP and go to `catalog/view/theme/YOURTHEME/template/product` and download product.tpl

find this line

```
<span class="reward"><small><?php echo $text_points; ?> <?php echo $points; ?></small></span><br />
<?php } ?>
```

Right after it paste this

```
<?php 
   echo round($weight,2). "kg";
?>
```

(Or paste it where ever you want to see it on the product page.)

after that go to `/catalog/controller/product` and open product.php

find this line

```
 $this->data['model'] = $product_info['model'];
```

and right after it paste  this line:

```
$this->data['weight'] = $product_info['weight'];
```

and you are pretty much done with that.

Hopefully i understood your question correctly.

Comment: hey, yes .. I'm Bulgarian :). This is working example, but can i fetch the weight unit dynamic.. here is hardcoded with . "kg";.. I want if the product is mg, to be with mg :)

Comment: Well you can hardcode it with an if else statement like if (weight >= 1) {echo the code above} else same code but with mg and change the number 2 to 3 or 4